# Order of a^k is a divisor of the order of a

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Exercise 10.D.2 from Pinter says:

> Let `a` be any element of finite order of a group `G`. Prove the following:
>
> The order of `a^k` is a divisor (factor) of the order of `a`.

## Approach 1

Let `ord(a) = n`.

Let `ord(a^k) = m`.

We must show that `m` is a divisor of `n`. I.e. `m|n`.

Since `ord(a^k) = m` we know that:

```
(a^k)^m = e

a^(km) = e
```

By theorem 5:

> Suppose an element `a` in a group has order `n`.
>
> Then `a^t = e` iff `t` is a multiple of `n`.
>
> ("`t` is a multiple of `n`" means that `t = nq` for some integer `q`).

```
km = nq
```

Solving for `m` (the order of `a^k`):

```
m = nq/k
```

It isn't clear that this shows that `m` is a divisor of `q`.

Any suggestions for this approach?

## Approach 2

(This is the approach suggested by the hint in the back of the book.)

Let `ord(a) = n`.

```
(a^k)^n
a^(nk)
(a^n)^k
e^k
e
```

At this point, the book says to use theorem 5.

By theorem 5:

```
nk = nq
```

Canceling `n` on both sides:

```
k = q
```

And that's all the book's hint has to offer. What's a good way forward?

---

*Note*: there is a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673851/operatornameordak-is-a-divisor-of-operatornameorda) on this site that specifically asks about *Approach 2* shown above. What I'm asking here is, if *Approach 1* is workable. It would also be nice to see *Approach 2* completed as the full answer in the linked question was not shown.

---

## Approach based on 2 above and Bill's answer

Let `ord(a) = n`.

Let `ord(a^k) = m`.

```
(a^k)^n
a^(nk)
(a^n)^k
e^k
e
```

Thus

```
(a^k)^n = e
```

Let's state theorem 5 in these terms

> Suppose an element `a^k` in a group has order `m`.
>
> Then `(a^k)^n = e` iff `n` is a multiple of `m`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ (a^{\large k})^{\large n} = 1\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm ord}(a^{\large k})\mid n,\, $ QED, $ $ if you already know [this Corollary](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242)  on order (= Theorem 5?).

Else, repeating its proof: the set $\,J\,$ of $\,j\,$ with $\,a^{\large kj}=1$ is closed under subtraction thus its least positive element $\,( = {\rm ord}\ a^k)\,$ divides all $\,j\in J, \,$ including $\,n\in J$.

Comment: Theorem 5 says: Let `ord(a) = n`. `a^t = e` iff `n | t`. That seems different from what you're saying above. Your statement involves `ord(a^k)`. Theorem 5 only deals in terms of `ord(a)`.

Comment: The *Theorem 5* from chapter 10 in Pinter is shown in the question.

Comment: As far as I know, the theorem in the answer you link to is not provided as a prerequisite in Pinter. But very interesting still, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @dharmatech Theorem 5 is the same as the Corollary that  I linked. Simply replace $a$ by $a^k$ in Theorem $5,$ as I do above in the first sentence.

Comment: I think I see where I misunderstood your note. Your 'n' is different from theorem 5 'n'.

Comment: @dharmatech I used your notation $\,n = {\rm ord}\,a,\ $ The name clash with the $\,n\,$ in your theorem is not a problem (rename it if need be).

Comment: OK, I see it now. Thank you. :-)

Comment: @dharmatech Great!

Answer (score 1):

Not to trivialize what you've done, but, why not use the fact that $\vert a^k\vert=\dfrac n{\operatorname {gcd}(n,k)}$, where $n=\vert a\vert$.

Comment: This is likely another good approach! However, here I'd like to consider approaches that only use facts which have presented thus far in the text (Pinter).