# Characterizations of divisors of the order of an element.

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, ideals, cyclic-groups

For prime numbers $p$ consider the two conditions

$({\rm A})\ \ \forall\:\! k\geq0\!:\ (-2)^k+1\not\equiv0\,\pmod{\!p}$

$({\rm B})\ \ \exists\:\! k\geq0\!:\ \ 2^{2k+1}+1\equiv0\,\pmod{\!p}$

Experimentation seems to show that the odd primes satisfying $\rm(A)$ are precisely the odd primes satisfying $\rm(B)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Might be easier to show that both are the set of primes of the form $p\equiv 3\pmod 8$.

Comment: @lulu: This is not correct, the first counterexample satisfying both (A) and (B) is p = 281

Comment: You're right!  Danger of looking at small numbers.

Comment: If $g$, the order of $2\pmod p$ were odd, for a $B-$prime, we'd have $2^{4k+2}\equiv 1 \pmod p$ so that $g\,|\,2(2k+1)$ which implies $g\,|\,2k+1$, a contradiction.  So $g$ must be even for a $B-$prime.  Similarly, for an $A-$prime, since if $g=2k+1$ then $(-2)^g\equiv -2^g\equiv -1\pmod p$, yielding a contradiction.

Comment: But that's not a full characterization of either set, just evidence.

Comment: Maybe something like $g\equiv 2 \pmod 4$.  For $p=281$, we have $g=70$, passing that test (which is far more of a guess than anything else).

Comment: Hint: both are equivalent to $\,-2\,$ has odd order $\!\bmod p\,$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/876013/242) for the nontrivial direction).

Comment: I added some remarks explaining how this is a special case of general results about the divisors of the order of an element. I also updated the title to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\rm\small (A),\:\!(B)\:\!$ are both equivalent to: $\,{-}2\:\!$ has *odd* order, since their logical negations are equivalent to $\:\!(2),(3)\:\!$ in the below *characterizations* of elements having **even** order (OP is  case $\,a = -2)$.

**Theorem** $ $ TFAE modulo $\rm\color{#c00}{prime}$ $\,\color{#0af}{p\neq 2},\,$ and $\,\color{#b70}{p\nmid a}$

$(1)\ \ \ {\bf 2}\mid o(a) :=\,$ order of $\,a\bmod{p},\,$  $ $ i.e. $ $ the order of $\,a\,$ is $ $ **even**

$(2)\ \ \ \color{#0a0}{a^k\,\equiv -1}\ $ for some $\,k\ge 0,\ \, $ i.e. some power $a^k\:\!$ has order $\bf 2$

$(3)\ \ \ a^{2j+1}\!\not\equiv 1\ \,$ for $\ $ all $\ $ $\,j\ge 0,\ \ $ i.e. $\ \ a^n\,\equiv\, 1\ \Longrightarrow\ n\,$ is **even**

**Proof** $\ \ (3\!\Rightarrow\!1)\,\ \ \color{#b70}{p\nmid a}\Rightarrow a^{o(a)}\!\equiv 1\, $ so $(3)\Rightarrow o(a)\neq 2j\!+\!1$ $\Rightarrow o(a)\,$ even.

$(1\!\Rightarrow\! 2)\,\ \ o(a)\!=\!2k\Rightarrow a^{2k}\equiv \color{#90f}{1\not\equiv a^k}\,$ so $\,0\equiv (\color{#90f}{a^k-1})(\color{#0a0}{a^k+1})\,\smash{\color{#c00}{\overset{\rm prime}\Rightarrow}} \color{#0a0}{a^k+1}\equiv 0$.

$(2\!\Rightarrow\!3)\ \, $ If $\,a^{2j+1}\!\equiv 1\,$ then $\,o(a)\,|\, 2j\!+\!1\,$ so odd $\:\!\underbrace{o(a)\,|\,2k}_{\color{#0a0}{\textstyle a^{2k}\equiv 1}}\Rightarrow o(a)\mid k\Rightarrow \underbrace{1\equiv \color{#0a0}{a^k\equiv -1}}_{\textstyle\Rightarrow\color{#0af}{p\mid 2\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow}}$

**Remark** $ $ The proof works in any integral $\rm\color{#c00}{domain}$ where $\,\color{#0af}{2\neq 0}\,$ and $\,a\,$ has $\rm\color{#b70}{finite \ order}$. Further we can view the above Theorem more *conceptually* as the special case $\,d=2\,$ of the following **characterizations of divisors $\,d\,$ of the order of $\,a.\,$** As in $\,(1\!\Rightarrow2)\,$ above, in an integral $\rm\color{c00}{domain}$ where $\,2\!\neq\!0\,$ we have $\,\color{#0a0}{o(a^k)=2\!\iff\! a^k = -1},\,$ so $(2)$ below is the same as $(2)$ above. Ditto for  $\:\!(3)\!:\,$ the contrapositive of $(3)$ below for $\,d=2\,$ is $\,2\nmid n\:\!\Rightarrow\:\! a^n\neq 1,\,$ which is $(3)$ above. These basic results are clarified when one studies cyclic groups and (principal) ideals and modules.

**Theorem** $ $ TFAE for an element $\,a\,$ of finite order in $\,\Bbb Z_n\,$ (or any monoid).

$(1)\ \ \ d\mid o(a) := $ order of $\,a$

$(2)\ \ \ \color{#0a0}{o(a^k) =d}\,$ for some $\,k\ge 0$

$(3)\ \ \ a^{n}= 1\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid n$

**Proof** $\ \ (1\!\Rightarrow\! 2)\,\ \ o(a)\!=\!dk\,\Rightarrow\, o(a^k)=d\,$ by [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3306841/242).

$(2\!\Rightarrow\!1)\ \ $ by [$\,o(a^k)\mid o(a),\,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3298323/242) i.e. $\,{a^{o(a)}\equiv 1}\Rightarrow (a^k)^{o(a)}\equiv 1\Rightarrow \color{#0a0}{d\ \mid\ }o(a)$

$(1\!\Rightarrow\! 3)\ \ \ a^n = 1\Rightarrow d\mid o(a)\mid n $

$(3\!\Rightarrow\! 1)\ \ \ a^{o(a)} = 1\Rightarrow d\mid o(a)$

---

Below is an *additive* analog for fractions. Call $\,d\neq 0 \,$  a denominator of a fraction $\,q\,$ if $\,dq \in \Bbb Z,\,$ i.e $\,q = c/d\,$ for some $\,c\in \Bbb Z$. The least denom $\,d\,$ [is the order](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1165413/242) of $\,q\,$ in the unit fraction circle group $\,\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z = $ fractions $\!\bmod 1,\,$ i.e. the least $\,d>0\,$ with $\,dq\equiv 0\pmod{\!\Bbb Z}$.

**Theorem** $ $ TFAE for a fraction $\,a\,$ over $\,\Bbb Z\,$ (or any PID) $\, $ [compare to prior Theorem]

$(1)\ \ \ d\mid \delta(a) := $ least denominator of $\,a$

$(2)\ \ \ \color{#0a0}{\delta(ka) =d}\,$ for some $\,k\ge 0$

$(3)\ \ \ na\in\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid n,\,$ i.e. $\,d\,$ divides every denominator $\,n\,$ for $\,a$

**Proof** $\ \ (1\!\Rightarrow\! 2)\,\ \ \delta(a)\!=\!dk\Rightarrow a = c/(dk),\, (c,d)\!=\!1\,$ so $\,\delta(ka) = \delta(c/d) = d$

$(2\!\Rightarrow\!1)\ \ $ by $\,\color{#0a0}{\delta(ka)}\mid \delta(a),\,$ i.e. $\,\delta(a)a\in\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\,\delta(a)(ka)\in\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}{d\ \mid\ } \delta(a)$

$(1\!\Rightarrow\! 3)\ \ \ na\in\Bbb Z\Rightarrow d\mid \delta(a)\mid n $

$(3\!\Rightarrow\! 1)\ \ \ \delta(a)a\in\Bbb Z\Rightarrow d\mid \delta(a),\,$ i.e. $\,d\,$ divides all denoms, including least denom.

---

The above Theorems can be unified when one studies (annihilator) ideals and modules.

Comment: Compare to [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/876013/242) that $\,\gcd(a^{2j+1}-1,a^k+1) = 1\,$ or $\,2\ \ $

Answer (score 9):

Note that [lulu's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4789428/are-these-sets-of-primes-equal#comment10182734_4789428) has the right general idea. First, note $p = 2$ satisfies condition A, but not condition B. Thus, considering only odd primes $p$, we use the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of $-2$ modulo $p$ (rather than of $2$), i.e.,

$$g = \operatorname{ord}_p(-2) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

If $g$ were even, then with $k = \frac{g}{2}$, we'd have

$$(-2)^{k} \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Condition A shows that $(-2)^{k} \not\equiv -1 \pmod{p}$, so $(-2)^{k} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, but then $1 \le k \lt g$. However, $g$ would then not be the multiplicative order. This contradiction means $g$ must be odd, i.e., it's of the form

$$g = 2k + 1, \;\; k \ge 0 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

We then have

$$(-2)^{2k+1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p} \;\to\; 2^{2k+1} \equiv -1 \pmod{p} \;\to\; 2^{2k+1} + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

i.e., condition B.

For the other direction, from the first modulo equation in \eqref{eq4A}, we have condition B meaning that $g$ in \eqref{eq1A} must be odd. Assume there's an integer $k$ where we have

$$(-2)^k + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p} \;\;\to\;\; (-2)^{2k} \equiv 1 \pmod{p} \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Thus, we have $g \mid 2k$. However, since $g$ is odd, this means $g \mid k$, but then

$$(-2)^k \equiv 1 \pmod{p} \;\;\to\;\; (-2)^k - 1 \pmod{p} \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

This contradicts \eqref{eq5A} unless $2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, but since we're considering only odd primes $p$, this isn't true. Thus, we get that condition B also implies condition A.

In conclusion, we have condition A and condition B implying each other for odd primes $p$, so your hypothesis is correct.

Comment: Thanks!  I was just writing up something similar, but less elegant (+1).

Comment: The "right general idea" is clearer when viewed in terms of divisors of the order - see the Remark in my answer.